# How to make taps be detected even slightly outside a collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I’m building a collection view which has multiple buttons separated one another by a few points. The layout is similar to a keyboard’s one.

￼[image]

Instead of using the given protocol stub (didSelectItemAt), I assign each cell a gesture recognizer in the cellForItemAt method. The gesture is a UITapGestureRecognizer:

```swift
  let touchUpGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer { recognizer in
           print(indexPath.row)
        }
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(touchUpGesture)
```

Obviously this gesture only works inside the cell.
But actually the user could make a mistake and tap the space slightly outside the cell so I would like to expand the receptive range of the gesture:

This is the current range where the tap gesture is detected:
￼
[image]

I also want this space to detect taps:

[image]

And I want the taps in the yellow zone to be associated to the left button and the ones in the pink zone to be associated to the pink zone:

[image]

If it was up to me I would make the cells slightly bigger and put another view inside of it to create the illusion of a button. This way I would achieve what I need but it’d totally be a heavier job.
I strongly believe there’s a better way to do what I need to but I can’t seem to find anything, is there a simpler and cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: I would simply use collectionview where I will not give any spacing and inside contentview i will drop another view which will have padding on all 4 sides and use didSelect.